# Wordpress: Show extra sidebar widgets based on size of adjoining content?

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, sidebar

I'd like to be able to show or hide content in a sidebar based on the height of the adjoining content div, but i'm not exactly sure if/how it can be done.

For example, on the blog page of my current project (http://djryanmcnally.pixelworx.it/?page_id=18) I have two widgets in the sidebar (one for latest tweets, and one for latest music news) however, as you can see on this page, the content of the blog posts (all test posts...) are much longer than the height of the two widgets, and would of course, get larger as more posts are added. This leaves a certain amount of blank space below the last widget in the sidebar, which I would like to fill based on the height of the adjoining `#content` div.

Suppose, for example, I also wanted to put into the sidebar some other content divs, such as `#latest-pics`, `#latest-mixes` and `#latest-events` but only if the adjoining content was large enough to create space for them, how would I do that?

I thought about using inline styling with variables, such as: (Pseudocode)

```
$i = #content(height);

if $i > 500px { $display1 = 'inline' } 
    else { $display1 = 'none' }

elseif $i > 1000px { $display2 = 'inline' } 
    else { $display2 = 'none' }

elseif $i > 1500px { $display3 = 'inline' }
    else { $display3 = 'none' }

.......

endif;
```

and using `<div id="latest-pics" style="display:<?php $display1 ?>;">` etc...

But, I highly doubt that would be anywhere even close to doing what i want, but, y'know, thought process, etc! lol!

I could of course use a floating sidebar that moves down as the use scrolls, but it'd be a nice touch to be able to do this somehow!

Any thoughts?

p.s - excuse the sketchy code example, i'm typing in a rush as I have to go to work!

Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: Probably easier to just put them in and use javascript to show / hide them based on height especially as height can change depending on orientation

Comment: I kinda thought that, but i'm not too familiar with javascript, so guidance would be appreciated! lol! I suppose I could attach the show/hide to the position of the scroll in a similar way to a floating sidebar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely looks like a javascript kinda thing. You want a vertically responsive layout, which is close to impossible to do with pure php.  The webserver loads the php code first then runs the javascript; meaning you can't reference javascript variables with your php.

Looks like your theme already has jquery installed so you might as well work with that.

In my opinion, I'd have all the divs on the side bar there but make sure they are all hidden (style="display:none"). Once the page has loaded and the content div is on the document, you can grab the height of the main content div on the left with

```
var h = $('#main').height();
```

Now the tricky part is knowing how the content in each of your sidebar widgets is going to be populated. You might want to put some limits on that to make things easier, or else you're going to require alot more post processing.

Once you know how you are going to handle the heights of you individual widgets, and what tier schema you want them to show in, you can show them as simply as

```
$('#widgetId').show();
```

Where '#widgetId' is going to be the id="" attribute on your div that you originally set to display: none.

So it would end up being something like

```
if(h > 100) $('#widget1').show();
if(h > 300) $('#widget2').show();
...
```

ect

If some of the widgets are too tall (say the widget2 is 500px usually) then you can set the height of the widget with javascript and handle the overflow however you'd like. You can use a overflow-y:scroll but that'd look pretty ugly, maybe just overflow:hidden, and make sure the height is at a consistently asthetic place for the widget.

Answer (score 1):

This was mind bugling for me too ;)  That's why I created a simple java script plugin that removes last widget or widgets from sidebar until sidebar height is equal as a content height.

This way you can add as much widgets as you want, and they will be removed if content is not high enough.

It works by default with Twenty Thirteen theme but you can use plugin settings to adopt it to any theme. It's called sidebarAutomizer and can be found at wp repository - http://wordpress.org/plugins/sidebarautomizer/

Comment: Hi there, I'm trying to use your plugin and it's great, except for one issue. The define element to remove setting removes ALL of the items with the given class, not just the last child. Is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I was going to do some commenting for suggestion; however, after some thoughts, I decided to go for answer area.

I think it is totally achievable. (Pseudocode)

1. set up sidebar area with fixed sidebar items with divs and define empty sidebar divs for other hidden content.
   (empty divs for hidden content: ...)
2. Loop start: get total scrolled_height by jQuery ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()).
3. get used_space_height including header and sidebar height
4. calculate the available_height by (scrolled_height - used_space_height)
5. see if next sidebar div height can fit into avaiable_height or not:
   4.1. if yes, load next sidebar div => go to step 5.
   4.2. if not. => go to step 6. end
6. load next sidebar div with ajax call to return content => go back to step 1.
7. Loop End.

Execute the above steps in javascript/jQuery by detecting that user stops scrolling.

Hope this helps.